# Implementing pagination with Java servlets, MySQL, and Javascript for the front end

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I'm having some trouble going through and visualizing how I accomplish pagination over a large dataset with a MySQL database, Java servlets, and using javascript to display the results.

I was working on a personal project with a small dataset to try and learn Java servlets / MySQL / JavaScript. I have a movie database with some movie names and other attributes in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I then have a Movie java bean:

```
// Movie bean
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    // Instance variables
    private Long            id;
    private String          title;
    private int             year;

    public Movie() {}

    // Setters
    public void setId    (long id)      { this.id = id;       }
    public void setTitle (String title) { this.title = title; }
    public void setYear  (int year)     { this.year = year;   }

    // Getters
    public long     getId()     { return id;    }
    public String   getTitle()  { return title; }
    public int      getYear()   { return year;  }
}
```

A `MovieDAO` which accesses the database and retrieves a list of all movies (below is an excerpt, assume I already connect to the database):

```
public class MovieDAO {
    private List<Movie> movies;

    private static ResultSet queryMovies(String st) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet res = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = dbcon.prepareStatement(st);
            res = ps.executeQuery();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error with movieDAO query");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public List<Movie> listMovies() throws SQLException {
        movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        ResultSet res = queryMovies("SELECT * FROM movies");
        while(res.next()) {
            Movie mov = new Movie();
            mov.setId(res.getLong("id"));
            mov.setTitle(res.getString("title"));
            mov.setYear(res.getInt("year"));
            movies.add(mov);
        }
        return movies;
    }
}
```

And finally my `MovieServlet` class which just displays all the information as a JSP variable that is a list:

```
@WebServlet("/movies")
public class MovieServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private MovieDAO movieDAO;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        movieDAO = new MovieDAO();
        try {
            List<Movie> movies = movieDAO.listMovies();
            request.setAttribute("movies", movies); // JSP variable: ${movies}
            request.getRequestDispatcher("movies.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Could not retrieve movies from the database",e);
        }
        movieDAO.closeMovieDAO();
    }
}
```

For the front end side of things I have a table which is populated through jsp and javascript. I originally just had a list of page numbers that were generated like so:

```
function showPageNumber() {
    var html = '';
    for(i = num_of_pages; i > 0; i--) { html += "<li class='page'><a>" + i + "</a></li>"; }
    $('.page').click(function() {
        result_min = ($(this).text() - 1) * results_per_page;
        result_max = $(this).text() * results_per_page;
        show(result_min,result_max);
    });
}

function show(min,max) {
    var $rows = $('#result_table');
    $rows.hide().slice(min, max).show();
}
```

Inside each row of the table with the id of `result_table`, I had the jsp variables. I also had a `sort` function so when the user clicked on each header of the table, it would sort by that header (ie. clicking `id` would sort by ascending `id`). This worked great with even a few thousand records of movies and was actually relatively quick.

I then inserted about 80,000 more records into the database. Much to no ones surprise, loading all of that data takes ages. Sorting it takes even longer.

To deal with this, I only want to let the user access a `next` button, the first ten page number buttons, and a `last` button which goes to the last page. I figured limiting the number of possible movies helps display the data faster.

My problem is now how can I sort every record and display everything correctly? For example, if the user sorts by `id` they will get a list of ascending `id`'s like so:

```
1  - movie1 - 1990
2  - movie2 - 1996
3  - movie3 - 1934
```

And if they click the same header the order will reverse like so:

```
3  - movie3 - 1934
2  - movie2 - 1996
1  - movie1 - 1990
```

But if I limit the amount of data retrieved, but I have a range of id's from 1 - 80,000 , how can I re-sort through all that data and retrieve the id values in reverse order now.. without having to call `SELECT` again?

Comment: check the [display-tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) for jsp level pagination or [data-table](https://datatables.net/) for jquery pagination

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I'll check out those links! Thank you :)